# Is there a way to place a command block with a command in a chest and/or dispenser?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I'm in the new snapshot and trying to make a random TP out of a dispenser and command blocks just like SethBling in his snapshot video just with the difference that I want to place the dispenser with an infinity amount of command blocks instead of 64 of each.

SethBling's video, relevant point about 14 minutes in:

Answer (score 5):

In the latest version (1.8.6) you cannot place command blocks with dispensers anymore, [due to an exploit which allowed malicious players to edit NBT data of a block](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-80671?focusedCommentId=228546&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-228546), specifically Command Blocks and Signs.
This exploit would allow any malicious player (if he had a command block) to edit in any command before placing it with a dispenser to trigger it in survival. This command block could do anything from giving them 64 diamond blocks to blowing the entire server sky high.

Answer (score 4):

To get a command block item with a command datatag:

- Place down a command block
- Type in the command you want
- Hold CTRL
- Middle click the command block

You should be able to see a "+NBT" in purple below the item name when you hover over it, indicating that the item has extra data. You can then put this in dispensers, chests, etc.

The easiest way to have limitless command blocks would be to have a "template dispenser" with all of your custom command blocks in that never gets activated, and then have the activation button clone the template down onto where you want the actual dispenser. A setup like this will work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

stay "command block" this place and write command "/summon Item ~ ~1 ~ {Item:{id:command_block,Count:1,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Command:your command}}}}" on top command block spawns drop command block up drop and stay place. ready! you have nbt command block